# javascript function only works debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have this javascript function which hide a column from a table:

```
function hideColumn (name) {
    column = $("#taula-thead td:contains("+name+")")[0].cellIndex;
    $("#taula-thead td:contains("+name+")").hide();
    $("#taula-tbody td:nth-child("+(column+1)+")").hide();
}
```

So, when the page load, another function read some cookies to see what columns should hide and calls this function for each of those columns. But the function only hides the thead part.

I debug it and... the code works when I'm debugging it. So I though maybe the problem was that it execute too fast or something and put the function within a setTimeout. But it also failed. Finally I tried writting it this way: `$("#taula-thead td:contains("+name+")").hide() && $("#taula-tbody td:nth-child("+(column+1)+")").hide();` but... it also fails.

So... I can't debug the code because it works with the debug and I'm not even sure what the problem could be.

**Update**

I find out the problem but not a good solution. I execute this function just after another function which insert a lot of rows. Look like when javascript execute this, the rows are not yet detected, so it only hides the thead part.

If I put the function inside a setTimeout with 50ms of delay, it works. If it has 30ms, it works sometimes. If it has 10ms, it never works. I'm searching a way to find out when the new rows are correctly setted and then execute this function.

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes. So this:

```
column = $("#taula-thead td:contains(" + name + ")")[0].cellIndex;
```

Actually your code is working see the snippet bellow. If there is a problem it's in the rest of your code that you didn't post.

**Working snippet:**

```js
function hideColumn(name) {
  column = $("#taula-thead td:contains(" + name + ")")[0].cellIndex;
  $("#taula-thead td:contains(" + name + ")").hide();
  $("#taula-tbody td:nth-child(" + (column + 1) + ")").hide();
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on a column to hide it</p>
<table>
  <thead id="taula-thead">
    <tr>
      <td onclick='hideColumn("ID")'>ID</td>
      <td onclick='hideColumn("name")'>name</td>
      <td onclick='hideColumn("some other column")'>some other column</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='taula-tbody'>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Aleksandr See the snippet above, your code is working just fine!

Comment: Is your code invoked AFTER the document is ready or perhaps before. See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ for more.